# How to populate a text field from UIPicker in Swift

Tags: swift

I found a custom UIPickerView (https://github.com/bendodson/MonthYearPickerView-Swift) to select only Month and Day. It pops up fine however I don't know how to populate the text field after I press "done". I found a few examples online which don't appear to be working for me.

```
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(donePressed))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelPressed))

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = themeColor1()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let StartDatePicker = MonthYearPickerView()
    StartDate.inputView = StartDatePicker
    StartDate.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}

func donePressed() {
    StartDate.text = ???
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}


func cancelPressed() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a delegate of picker view ..

```
pickerView.delegate = self
```

then implement its method named as

```
   func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return yourList.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return yourList[row]
}
```

Now, if you want picker view to appear on touching TextField you need to do this

```
textField.inputView = pickerView
```

Also implement

```
  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    yourTextfield.text = yourList[row]
}
```

so that when you select any row in a pickerView, the title of that row will be assign to your text field ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the delegate method for picker view, didSelectRow.  I have a similar picker view and I have multiple textviews.  So in the method I check to see who is the first responder and then I set that text view to a string that is equal to the picker value.

Make sure your view controller conforms to UIPickerViewDelegate and datasource which it seems you have already done.

```
In the function make an if statement:  if (yourTextView.isFirstResponder)
create a string to hold the picker value: myString = pickerView array object at index
assign that string to your textview:  StartDate.text = myString
```

This is only pseudo code, because I wrote all my methods in Objective C.  Make a comment if you need further assistance.